# How do I make a function in django to add comments to my reviews

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I have a website made on Django and the users able to leave a review and Ive tried to make it so they can add comments, however they add a comment it just saves it to the database rather then adding it to the post. If anyone knows how I could change my code so that it instead adds the comments to the review that they message on rather then them not appearing on the website at all.

**views.py:**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect #Render is used to show the HTML, and redirect is used when the user needs to be sent to a different page automatically.
        from .models import Review #This imports the Review database.
        from .forms import ReviewForm, CommentForm #This imports the comments and review form.
        from django.utils import timezone 
        from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required #This requires the user to be logged in.

        def review(request):
            return render(request, 'review/review.html') 

        @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/') 
        def review_new(request): 
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = ReviewForm(request.POST) 
                if form.is_valid(): 
                    post = form.save(commit=False) 
                    post.date = timezone.now() 
                    post.author = request.user 
                    post.save() 
                    return redirect('/review') 
            else: 
                form=ReviewForm() 
            return render(request, 'review/post_edit.html', {'form': form}) 

        def add_comment_to_post(request): 
            if request.method == "POST": 
                form = CommentForm(request.POST) 
                    comment = form.save(commit=False) 
                    comment.Review = review 
                    comment.save() #This will save the comment to the database.
                    return redirect('reivew': review) 
            else:
                form = CommentForm() 
            return render(request, 'review/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py:**

```
        from django.db import models 
        from django.conf import settings 
        from django.utils import timezone 

        class Review(models.Model): 
            title = models.CharField(max_length=140) 
            body = models.TextField(max_length=3000) 
            date = models.DateTimeField()
            author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, `on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)` 

        class comment(models.Model): 
            review = models.ForeignKey('review.Review', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', null=True) 
            author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) 
            text = models.TextField(max_length=3000) 
            created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.text
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path 
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView 
from review.models import Review 
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', ListView.as_view( 
        queryset=Review.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25], 
        template_name="review/review.html")),
    re_path('(?P<pk>(\d+))',DetailView.as_view(model=Review, template_name="review/post.html")), 
    path('new/', views.review_new, name='review_new'), 
    path('new/comment', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'), 

]
```

Comment: This line: `comment.Review = review` you haven't defined `review` and you're setting a property `Review` that has nothing to do with the field `review`. Well, you have defined `review` earlier in the file, but `review` is just a function (`def review(request):`). First you should get the review somehow: the form to submit the comment should include the id of review in the url or as an input field. And then you fetch it `comment_review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)` and then `comment.review = comment_review` before saving.

Comment: would have been helpful to see the CommentForm class definition and the template files.

Comment: Hi when i put what you said and when I now go to add a comment it says that review_id is not defined

Comment: hi @harry boyd was my answer below of any help. If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you should change `comment.Review = review` to something like `comment.review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)` where `review_id` is an id passed from the form. Also notice that your Comment model allows the review to be null, which means currently you are adding comments without linking them correctly to the original post/review they should be related to.

Comment: Hi when i put what you said and when I now go to add a comment it says that review_id is not defined

Comment: @harryboyd an you update the question with the forms.py ? I think you can add a field to the form for the review I'd that this comment belongs to.

Comment: @harryboyd was that of any help? I think this video might also help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb5ACR0jUyw (you need to listen to it carefully because of the guy's accent)